# How To Add and Remove UIViewControllers to other UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that contains a button. When I press the button I add a child view controller using the following.

```
- (IBAction)loadEditScreen:(id)sender {

self.editViewController = [[EditViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:self.editViewController];
[self.editViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

self.editViewController.view.alpha = 0;
[self.editViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:self.editViewController.view];

[self.editViewController setupImage:self.selectedImageView.image];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0.0
                    options:0
                 animations:^{
                     self.editViewController.view.alpha = 1;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];

}
- (void)closeEditScreen {

[self.editViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.editViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.editViewController removeFromParentViewController ];

}
```

Now the problem seems to be that I am not sure how to go about removing the child view controller when needed. Within the child controller I have a button that calls the following.

```
- (IBAction)closeEditScreen:(id)sender {

HomeViewController *tmpController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
[tmpController closeEditScreen];

/*[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0.0
                    options:0
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.alpha = 0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
                     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];*/

}
```

The problem seems to be that the method gets called but nothing actually happens. The View isn't removed even though I know that method is working because I have set breakpoints.

Any help would be great. I just want to add a childviewcontroller and then have a button in the child that removes the childviewcontroller when pressed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check the SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844432/container-uiviewcontroller-not-releasing-its-child-view-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `EditViewController closeEditScreen:` (the child VC) you are creating a new instance of `HomeViewController` (the parent VC) and invoke `closeEditScreen` on that new instance. This is wrong, you don't want a new instance.

What you want to do instead is invoke `closeEditScreen` on the `HomeViewController` instance that already exists and that created your child VC. Try this:

```
- (IBAction)closeEditScreen:(id)sender
{
  // This is the instance of HomeViewController that you need
  UIViewController* parentViewController = self.parentViewController;
  // Cast the type so that you can invoke closeEditScreen without a compiler warning
  HomeViewController* parentHomeViewController = (HomeViewController*)parentViewController;
  [parentHomeViewController closeEditScreen];
}
```

While this should get you the correct `HomeViewController` instance to work with, I am not sure whether your approach to remove a child VC may not have other problems. If you do encounter more problems then you should definitely read through the VC programming guide mentioned in Cy-4AH's answer.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have solved the problem. I thought it may have been because of the new instance but wasn't sure how to call back to the parent view controller. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need read [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1). Your code is completely wrong.